# How do I create a Sales Territory map with location detection using Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, gis

I would like to divide the world map into territories.

My area data is in the form of country names, state names, counties and zip codes.

I'm planning to use Google Maps API, unless there is a better tool.

1. How do I define these areas? Do I use an overlay? Can my disparate geo data be combined into overlays?
2. Once I have these areas defined how do I take a location and check what territory it's in?

So far I have only collected the data defining the territories and researched "Sales Area Maps" and custom maps online.

Answer (score 1):

The GoogleMaps itself is a fragment. You can have Shapes overlay inside your Map Fragment.

I am giving some ideas on how you can define the territory.

1) Using Bbox (Boundary box) -- This is a cube. You define metacenter of this cube. You provide the diagonal length. You create a function to create a Bbox cube. Each time you compare your points with that Bbox's metacenter (X,Y,Z). If your point is greater than all lowest X1, Y1, Z1 and smaller than all highest X2, Y2, Z2 then you are inside that territory. Here, (X1, Y1, Z1) are the Geo coordinates of the lowest corner of you territory Bbox, and (X1, Y1, Z1) are the Geo coordinates of the highest corner of your territory **bobox**.

USGS uses this concept to define the territory. Here is the link:

```
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php
```

[image]

2) Since you already said, your territory is based on States, city names. The BBOX does not seem to work here in your scenario. So, you have to define your own custom territory. You can use reverse geo coder API to get some set of geo-coordinates. Then, you using those set of Geo coordinates, draw a Shapes using Polygon. Below gives you how you can draw custom Shapes (custom territory).

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines
```

After you draw your custom area (territory), you now remained to check how a marker (a location) belongs to that territory or not? 
Ans: find two each point that draws a straight line between two geo-coordinates. For instance, if you use 10 geo-coordinates to draw a Shape, you can have a pair of geo-coordinates {(coordinate 1, coordinate 6), (coordinate 2, coordinate 7), (coordinate 3, coordinate 8), (coordinate 4, coordinate 9), (coordinate 5, coordinate 10). Now, you put these pair of coordinates in an ArrayList. To know, if your point is inside that territory, you have to iteratively compare if your point is inside that pair of coordinates in your ArrayList. For better accuracy, you have to use many geo coordinates to draw your territory. This is the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's critical that the territory borders align with geo borders: state, county and country borders. If I draw them myself there will be mistakes and it will take a very long time to divide the world into many regions by hand.

Comment: @Webster, let me go through a little bit on Google Maps APIs.